# How do I calculate this integral $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{+\infty} \exp(-ax^2)\sin(x) \,dx$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

So far I got: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}} \exp \left( x^2-\frac{1}{4a} \right) \,dx$. But, I ran into a snag. Any ideas how to pull out the value of the integral to within $O(a^3)$?

Comment: What you have in the main text is basically Dawson's integral: http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.2.E5 (i.e., it is $\frac{1}{{\sqrt a }}F\left( {\frac{1}{{2\sqrt a }}} \right)$)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\int_0^\infty\exp(-x^2)\sin(x)~dx$ Evaluate Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618694/int-0-infty-exp-x2-sinxdx-evaluate-integral)

Comment: unfortunately not, the series expansion of Dawson function may help, but even so I do not understand how to take it analytically.

Comment: From the asymptotic expansion of the Dawson integral, we obtain that your integral is $1 + 2a + 12a^2  + \mathcal{O}(a^3 )$ as $a\to 0$. Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have a nice closed form. It can be stated in terms of the [Dawson plus function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function)

$$\int_0^\infty \exp(-xt^2)\sin(t)\mathrm{d}t=\frac{D_+\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)}{\sqrt{x}}$$
Near the origin it has the Taylor expansion
$$D_+(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k2^k}{(2k+1)!_2}x^{2k+1}$$

Whereas at infinity it has the asymptotic expansion
$$D_+(x)=\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{4x^3}+\frac{3}{8x^5}+\cdots+\frac{(2k-1)!_2}{2^{k+1}x^{2k+1}}+O(x^{-2k-3})$$

**edit:** Where $!_2$ indicates the "double factorial". I dislike the "$!!$" notation.

Comment: Also important - the integral only converges for $\operatorname{Re}(x)>0$.